# ReferenceError: GetCamposDinamicoGrid is not defined

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Preciso de um help, não consigo resolver uma parada, quando eu carrego uma telinha web, tenho um botão adicionar que criar 3 campos html e assim vai adicionando um em baixo do outro, mas ta dando pau, pois tenho minha pagina PartialComposicaoEmail.cshtml abaixo com os campos:

```html
@using Itau.DPE.MesaPrecos.DAO.Models;
@model List<TB_Campos_Email>


@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="table table-striped Exp-Table">
            <tr class="table-tr">
                <th style="text-align: center">Origem</th>
                <th style="text-align: left">Campo</th>
                <th style="text-align: left">Alias</th>
                <th style="text-align: center"></th>
            </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr class="listCamposDinamicos">
                    @*Origem Campo Validador*@
                   <td>
                             <select class="selectpicker selvalorOrigem" data-live-search="true" aria-expanded="true">
                             
                                    <option value="@item.Origem" selected>@item.Origem 0</option>
                                                            
                                    @*<option value="0" selected></option>*@
                            </select>                      
                    </td>

                    @*Campo Validador*@
                    <td>
                            <select class="selectpicker selvalorCampo" data-live-search="true" aria-expanded="true">
                             
                                    <option value="@item.Valor_Campo" selected>@item.Valor_Campo 0</option>
                                                            
                                    @*<option value="0" selected></option>*@
                            </select>
                    </td>
                 

                 <td class="text" style="text-align: left;" id="tdValor">
                            <input type="text" class="txtAlias" value="@item.Alias" style="width: 215px;" maxlength="100" aria-expanded="true" />

                  @*Botão Remover*@
                   <td class="text-center">
                       <a href="#" id="btn-remover-comp">
                           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash exp-glyphicon-remove" style="font-size: large"></span>
                       </a>
                   </td>
                 </td>
           </tr>
        }
    </table>
  </div>    
}
```

Tenho meu Email.js que tem as funções GetCamposDinamicoGrid e AddCamposDinamico, ta dando pau na GetCamposDinamicoGrid com o erro: 
message: "GetCamposDinamicoGrid is not defined"
stack: "ReferenceError: GetCamposDinamicoGrid is not defined↵    at eval (eval at GetCamposDinamicoGrid (http://localhost:54771/MesaPrecos/Scripts/Email.js:583:9), :1:1)↵    at GetCamposDinamicoGrid (http://localhost:54771/MesaPrecos/Scripts/Email.js:583:9)↵    at AddCamposDinamico (http://localhost:54771/MesaPrecos/Scripts/Email.js:600:32)↵    at HTMLDivElement. (http://localhost:54771/MesaPrecos/Scripts/Email.js:5:9)↵    at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (http://localhost:54771/MesaPrecos/Scripts/Core/jquery-1.12.0.min.js:3:12344)↵    at HTMLBodyElement.r.handle (http://localhost:54771/MesaPrecos/Scripts/Core/jquery-1.12.0.min.js:3:9071)"
**proto**: Error

```js
 function GetCamposDinamicoGrid() {
        
        var obj = [];
        debugger;

        $(".listCamposDinamicos").each(function () {
            var origemCampo = {};

            origemCampo.origem = $('.selvalorOrigem').find(":selected").text();  //$(this).find(".selvalorOrigem").text();
            origemCampo.valorCampo = $('.selvalorCampo').find(":selected").text();  //$(this).find(".selvalorCampo").text();
            origemCampo.alias = $(this).find(".txtAlias").text();

            obj.push(origemCampo);
        });

        return obj;
    }

    function AddCamposDinamico(){
        MensagemBloqueio("Aguarde...");
        var listacamposEmail = GetCamposDinamicoGrid();
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Email/AddCamposDinamico',
            data: { 'listCamposDinamicos': JSON.stringify(listacamposEmail) },
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            statusCode: {
                200: function (resultado) {
                    DesbloquearPagina();
                    $('#divCamposDinamicos').slideDown();
                    $('#divCamposDinamicos').html(resultado);
                },
                99: function (resultado) {
                    DesbloquearPagina();
                    ExibirMensagem(resultado.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

A function AddCamposDinamico manda pra uma controller abaixo para descerializar os campos e criar:

```js
 public ActionResult AddCamposDinamico(string listacamposEmail)
        {
            var campos = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<TB_Campos_Email>>(listacamposEmail);

            if (campos == null)
                campos = new List<TB_Campos_Email>();

            campos.Add(new TB_Campos_Email { Origem = "", Valor_Campo = "", Alias = "" });

            Response.StatusCode = 200;

            return PartialView("PartialComposicaoEmail", campos);
        }
```

Não sei se é forma que estou usando no jquery para capturar os selects que ta dando pau, pois quando chega na linha var campos = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize>(listacamposEmail); traz o erro {"Valor não pode ser nulo.\r\nNome do parâmetro: input"}
Já tentei fazer varias alterações, mas permanece, fico no aguardo de um help.

Answer (score 0):

Segue abaixo o que eu estava querendo fazer, são três campos, dois optionlists e um input text, com um botão adicionar, era necessário recriar mais vezes os mesmos campos:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
    <table class="table table-striped Exp-Table">
        <tr class="table-tr">
            <th style="text-align: center">Origem</th>
            <th style="text-align: left">Campo</th>
            <th style="text-align: left">Alias</th>
            <th style="text-align: center"></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr class="listCamposEmail">
            <td>
                <select class="selectpicker form-control selOrigemCampo" onchange="CarregarCamposPorOrigem(this)">
                    @{pSelect = (item.TB_Parametro_CampoValidador.Origem_Campo == 1) ? "selected" : ""; }
                    <option value="1" @pSelect>WorkFlow</option>

                    @{pSelect = (item.TB_Parametro_CampoValidador.Origem_Campo == 2) ? "selected" : ""; }
                    <option value="2" @pSelect>SAS</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td>
                <select class="selectpicker form-control selIdCampo" data-live-search="true">
                    @if (item.ID_Campo > 0) {
                        <option value="@item.ID_Campo" selected>@item.TB_Parametro_CampoValidador.Nome_Campo</option>
                    }
                    else{
                        <option value="0" selected>Selecione...</option>
                    }


                    @foreach (var campo in listaCampos.Where(c => c.ID_Campo != item.ID_Campo && c.Origem_Campo == item.TB_Parametro_CampoValidador.Origem_Campo))
                    {
                        <option value="@campo.ID_Campo">@campo.Nome_Campo</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control txtAlias" value="@item.Alias" maxlength="100">
            </td>

            <td class="text-center">
                <a href="#" id="btn-excluir-campo" onclick="RemoverCampo(this)">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash exp-glyphicon-remove" style="font-size: large"></span>
                </a>

                <input type="hidden" class="selIdCampoEmail" value="@item.ID_Campos_Email" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
}
```

Agora o script Jquery que conta quantos campos htmls já estão criados:

```
function GetCamposEmailGrid() {
var obj = [];
debugger;

var idEmail = ($('#idAlt') != undefined && $('#idAlt').val() != undefined) ? $('#idAlt').val() : 0;

$(".listCamposEmail").each(function () {
    var campo = {};

    campo.ID_Campos_Email = $(this).find('.selIdCampoEmail').val();
    campo.ID_Email = idEmail;
    campo.ID_Campo = $(this).find('.selIdCampo').val();
    campo.Alias = $(this).find(".txtAlias").val();
    campo.IS_Valor = true;

    obj.push(campo);
});

return obj;
```

}

Controller que faz descerialização e cria um novos campos html.

```
public ActionResult AddCampoEmail(int idEmail, string camposEmail)
    {
        try
        {
            var campos = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<TB_Campos_Email>>(camposEmail);

            if (campos == null)
                campos = new List<TB_Campos_Email>();

            var camposValidadores = new CampoValidadorBLL().ListarCamposWFSAS();

            ViewBag.CamposValidadores = camposValidadores;

             foreach (var item in campos)
                 item.TB_Parametro_CampoValidador = camposValidadores.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID_Campo == item.ID_Campo) ?? new TB_Parametro_CampoValidador { Origem_Campo = 1 };

            campos.Add(new TB_Campos_Email { ID_Email = idEmail, ID_Campo = 0, TB_Parametro_CampoValidador = new TB_Parametro_CampoValidador { Origem_Campo = 1 }, Alias = "" });

            Response.StatusCode = 200;
            return PartialView("PartialComposicaoEmail", campos);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExibirMensagem("Erro: " + ex.Message, ETipoMensagem.Erro, 99);
            return PartialView("Mensagens");
        }
    }
```